# Focus input on load of Modal in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native's [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) component. I would like to focus on a TextInput & show keyboard when the Modal is visible.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a reference to the text input and call the focus method from the onShow handler of the Modal.

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Modal, Text, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';
    
    export default class ModalExample extends Component {
    
      state = {
        modalVisible: false,
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
            <Modal
              animationType={"slide"}
              transparent={false}
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}
              onShow={() => { this.textInput.focus(); }}
              >
             <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', marginTop: 50, width: 300, padding: 50, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
              <View>
                <Text>Hello World!</Text>
                <TextInput
                  ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
                  style={{ padding: 20, backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'red' }}
                />
              </View>
             </View>
            </Modal>
    
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
              this.setState({modalVisible: true});
            }}>
              <Text>Show Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
    
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer! autoFocus just doesn't seem to work well with Modals in React-Native, but this work-around does an great job of doing the same thing. +1

Answer (score 8):

Set the property `autoFocus` on the TextInput to true:

```
<TextInput
  autoFocus={true}
/>
```